# Multiple balls - Bouncing balls - Java

Tags: java

I am wring the bouncing ball program in java. And I Now have one bouncing ball, I would like to have at least five bouncing balls. I have tried a few ways to do it, however, I only end up with one ball or error.

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed? This in the piece of code used for the one ball, is it possible to rewrite this piece of code to get multiple balls in a neat way?

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class World {

private final double width, height; 

private Ball[] balls; 
private final Rectangle pad; 

public World(double width, double height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    balls = new Ball[1];
    balls[0] = new Ball(10, 10); 
    balls[0].setVelocity(75.0, 100.0);




    pad = new Rectangle(width / 2, 0.9 * height, 
            width / 8, height / 32);
}


public void move(long elapsedTimeNs) {
    balls[0].move(elapsedTimeNs);
    constrainBall(balls[0]);
    checkForCollisionWithPad(balls[0]);
}


public Ball[] getBalls() {
    return (Ball[]) balls.clone();
}


public Rectangle getPad() {
    return pad;
}


public void setPadX(double x) {
    if (x > width) {
        x = width;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        x = 0;
    }

    pad.setX(x);
}


private void constrainBall(Ball ball) {
    double x = ball.getX(), y = ball.getY();
    double dx = ball.getDx(), dy = ball.getDy();
    double radius = ball.getRadius();


    if (x < radius) {
        dx = Math.abs(dx);
    } else if (x > width - radius) {
        dx = -Math.abs(dx);
    }
    if (y < radius) {
        dy = Math.abs(dy);
    } else if (y > height - radius) {
        dy = -Math.abs(dy);
    }

    ball.setVelocity(dx, dy);
}


private void checkForCollisionWithPad(Ball ball) {
    if (ball.intersectsArea(
            pad.getX(), pad.getY(), pad.getWidth(), pad.getHeight())) {
        double dx = ball.getDx();
        // set dy negative, i.e. moving "up"
        double newDy = -Math.abs(ball.getDy()); 
        ball.setVelocity(dx, newDy);
    }
 }
}
```

Main

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Bounce extends Application {

private World world;

private Canvas canvas; 
private AnimationTimer timer;

protected class BounceTimer extends AnimationTimer {

    private long previousNs = 0;


    @Override
    public void handle(long nowNs) {

        if (previousNs == 0) {
            previousNs = nowNs;
        }


        world.move(nowNs - previousNs); 

        previousNs = nowNs;


        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();


        gc.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());


        Rectangle pad = world.getPad();
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        double x = pad.getX(), y = pad.getY(),
                w = pad.getWidth(), h = pad.getHeight();
        gc.fillRoundRect(x, y, w, h, h, h);


        for (Ball b : world.getBalls()) {
            b.paint(gc);
        }



    }
}



@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.WHITESMOKE);

    canvas = new Canvas(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
    root.getChildren().add(canvas);

    stage.setTitle("Bounce");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.show();

    world = new World(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    timer = new BounceTimer();
    timer.start();

    canvas.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
                    world.setPadX(me.getX());
                }
            });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void showAlert(String message) {
    alert.setHeaderText("");
    alert.setTitle("Alert!");
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.show();
}

private final Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
}
```

Ball

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;



public class Ball {

public static final double BILLION = 1_000_000_000.0;

private double x, y; // position of the balls center
private double dx, dy; // velocity measured in pixels/second
private double radius;
private Color color;




    public Ball(double x0, double y0) {


    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    radius = 10;
    color = Color.MAGENTA;
}


public Ball(double x0, double y0, double rad, Color col) {


    x = x0;
    y = y0;
    radius = rad;
    color = col;

}

Ball(int i, int i0, Color BLUEVIOLET) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
}

  public void setColor(Color col) { // setColor
    color = col; }

public double getX() {
    return x;
}


public double getY() {
    return y;
}


public void setX(double newX) {
    x = newX;
}


public void setY(double newY) {
    y = newY;
}


public double getRadius() {
    return radius;
}


public double getDx() {
    return dx;
}


public double getDy() {
    return dy;
}


public void setVelocity(double newDx, double newDy) {
    dx = newDx;
    dy = newDy;
}


public void moveTo(double newX, double newY) {
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
}



public void move(long elapsedTimeNs) {
    x += dx * elapsedTimeNs / BILLION;
    y += dy * elapsedTimeNs / BILLION;
}


public void paint(GraphicsContext gc) {
    gc.setFill(color);
    // arguments to fillOval: see the javadoc for GraphicsContext
    gc.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
}


public boolean intersectsArea(
        double rectX, double rectY,
        double rectWidth, double rectHeight) {


    double closestX = clamp(x, rectX, rectX + rectWidth);
    double closestY = clamp(y, rectY, rectY + rectHeight);


    double distanceX = x - closestX;
    double distanceY = y - closestY;


    return (distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY)
            < (radius * radius);
}


private double clamp(double value, double lower, double upper) {
    if (value < lower) {
        return lower;
    }
    if (value > upper) {
        return upper;
    }
    return value;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? I don't see you trying to create anything and not succeeding. Can you show your **main** ?

Comment: In your `move` method, you're only targeting a single ball.

Comment: I have updated the main code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stormblessed said, you are only targeting one ball in your `move` method.
You should do:

```
public void move(Ball ball, long elapsedTimeNs) {
    ball.move(elapsedTimeNs);
    constrainBall(ball);
    checkForCollisionWithPad(ball);
}
```

Edit: Since you want the handler method to accept only the `elapsedTimeNs` argument, do:

```
public void move(long elapsedTimeNs) {
    for (Ball ball : balls) {
        ball.move(elapsedTimeNs);
        constrainBall(ball);
        checkForCollisionWithPad(ball);
    }
}
```

Edit 2: You should probably have a method that creates a new ball, for convenience:

```
public Ball newBall(double x, double y, double velocity1, double velocity2) {
    Ball tmp = new Ball(x, y);
    tmp.setVelocity(velocity1, velocity2);
    balls.add(tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

Edit 3: The reason it throws an error is that you designated `balls` to have only one index position by using `balls = new Ball[`**1**`]`. You should use an `ArrayList` (`java.util.ArrayList`) instead, like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

ArrayList<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>;
```

You should now use `balls.add` and `balls.get` instead of `=` and `[]`. References have been updated accordingly.

Comment: It says that in the Main, in handle method that method move in the Main can not be handled to given types: 
required; ball, long
found: long 
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Thank you! I now tried implementing more balls to bounce, however, the methods I used do not work.

`balls[0] = new Ball(10, 10);
balls[0].setVelocity(75.0, 100.0);
balls[1] = new Ball(10, 10); 
balls[1].setVelocity(75.0, 100.0);
balls[2] = new Ball(10, 10);         
balls[2].setVelocity(65.0, 100.0);`

However, I am not able to run the program if doing this, Is there another way to implement more balls?

Comment: Never mind! Got it to work, forgot to change the number of items in the array. thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great! I updated the code so it could use an `ArrayList`, so you can use any amount of balls.